# copy data from one table to another existing table using sql

Tags: sql

I know we could use

```
Insert Into table_name(cloumn_names) 
   Select column_names 
   From table_name
```

but how about `Select Into`? Can we also use `Select Into` to copy data from one table to another EXISTING table using? I mean can we specify the column names of the latter table using `Select Into`? 
Thx!

Comment: `SELECT INTO` (at least for **SQL Server** - you're not clear on what concrete database you're using) only **creates new tables** - it's **NOT** usable to insert data into existing tables.

Answer (score 4):

You can use insert into select syntax

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

It basically selects columns from table1 and respectively insert in table 2

Answer (score 1):

**SELECT INTO**

This method is used when table is not created earlier and needs to be created when data from one table is to be inserted into newly created table from another table. New table is created with same data types as selected columns.

[Inserting Rows by Using SELECT INTO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190750%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: sorry i cannot... not enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
UPDATE [TestDB].[dbo].[Table1]
    SET [Content] = (
    Select [TestDB].[dbo].[Table2].[Content] from Table2 where ID= 'XYZ')
    WHERE [ID] = 'XYZ'
    GO
```